# Проблема с кодировкой в Python3

Tags: python, charset

Начал изучать python и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

У меня есть строка: b'\xd0\xad\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe

Я провожу с ней следующие манипуляции:

```
t_hash = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf-8")
letter = base64.b64decode(t_hash).decode("utf-8")
```

В итоге, если я вывожу  *letter*  на экран, то все замечательно, но если я записываю это в файл

```
f_message.write(letter)
```

То появляется следующее:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 
0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Что я делаю не так? Как справится с проблемой?

Comment: Дайте угадаю: вы открыли файл как байтовый, а пытаетесь писать юникодную строку?

Comment: @andreymal: это вернуло бы TypeError на Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Открывая файл на запись и чтение необходимо указать в параметрах

```
encoding="utf-8"
```

Comment: если входные данные не используют utf-8, то это неправильно.